# cast 'object' type property to knownType in wcf client

Tags: c#, wcf, object, casting, datacontract

I have created a WCF service with a simple method with a property of type 'object' because this property is intended to be used with different types of objects, but when i cast the property to another type it throws an invalidCastException. The Service looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(List<ItemDataContract>))]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    ItemContainer GetList();
}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(List<ItemDataContract>))]
public class ItemContainer
{
    [DataMember]
    public object Data { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class ItemDataContract
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

And the method's implementation:

```
public ItemContainer GetList()
{
    return new ItemContainer
    {
        Data = new List<ItemDataContract> {new ItemDataContract{ Id = "1"}, new ItemDataContract{Id = "2"}
    };
}
```

On the client's side i have the call to the method:

```
Service1 _proxy = new Service1();
var result = _proxy.GetList();
return (List<ItemDataContract>)result.Data;
```

the problem is that i get an invalid cast exception on the client's side because the result.Data internally is of type 'object' instead of being a List, even if use the serviceKnowntype and knownType.

How do I make this cast possible?

Comment: Is it an option to make ItemContainer generic and just specify the type per operation?

Comment: yes Mark, but then in the implementation you would have a diferent ItemContainer<T> per  type of object you want to use, resulting in a diferent type for each one of this in the Service Reference on the client's side.

Comment: Well that would be my personal preference anyway because otherwise the client would need to know the exact implementation detail of the service in order to do the correct cast. As to the problem at hand, you _could_ try (no idea if it will work) putting the data and service contracts in an assembly that's referenced by both the client and the service. When you import the service reference it will reference the ones from the shared assembly. Maybe the cast will work then. Otherwise there's probably just not enough type information for the runtime to know they are the same class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was taking too much time to try casting object type, so i ended up creating a new class called Data, from which every other class that i had in the IService1 interface inherited, and assigned this type for the Data property. For the enumerable types i created a property specifically for each one of those inside de Data class. Im sure is not the best answer but it works using the known types with the ItemContainer.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this I hope this will help you......

```
    Service1 _proxy = new Service1();
    List<ItemContainer> result = _proxy.GetList();
    return result.Data.ToList<datatype>();
```

Comment: tried but didn't work, c# dont allow the object type to use ToList method

Comment: You are using var tahts why u cannot use Tolist Method